# WIndows freeze on startup

Tags: windows, boot, freeze

on normal mode it freezes.

on safe mode, it tries to log in with user called user (which is mine) but i changed the password..

if i remove the password, everything goes back to normal...

Comment: At what stage does it freeze?

Comment: at the welcome screen saying "windows is starting up"

Answer (score 0):

I'd run a virus and malware check.

It seems odd that it's trying to auto-login without you knowing. It's perfectly possible to set auto-login (see [here for Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231) for example), but I would have thought you'd have remembered doing that.

Did the problem start at the same time you changed the password? The password is stored in the registry for auto-login to use, so you'd need to update that as well for it to continue working.